# What is the use of the Schema.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What exactly is the use of the Schema.rb file?

Answer (score 6):

It is a generated file when you run your migrations. To the best of my knowledge it has two uses:

- Your database schema is in one place and can be viewed and reviewed.
- You can load your database in one shot by use `rake db:schema:load` instead of having to walk through your migrations

Answer (score 3):

This file is reproduced every time you execute a migration. It reproduces the entire schema of your database. It is also used by certain commands in migration in Rails to avoid redoing all the migrations one by one (in the case of a migration reset for instance).

It is also the only place when you can see all your tables at once for the reference of columns. But I suggest you to use the gem annotate in order to document your models with all column names. It's easier to work like this than having to go to schema.rb everytime you want details about the DB structure of your model.

Answer (score 2):

One good usage of schema.rb is whenever we run rake test, it prepares the test database instantly using schema.rb(without running the migrations).